# Regex for legal citations

Tags: regex

I have read countless tutorials and found the free, online [regex tester](https://regex101.com), a great resource, but still cannot fashion the proper regular expression to capture legal case citations in this format.

```
State v. Starks, 196 Ohio App.3d 589, 2011-Ohio-2344.
```

I was able to divine this:

```
(?!.*\d)
```

to capture only to the last number in the string above, but then it stops at the `196` above instead of proceeding to the last number in the string following `Ohio-` which is what I want it to do.

Any regex experts out there can help me with this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex:

```
^.*?(?:\d+\D+)*(\d+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oQZ5KX/1/)

Explanation: Fully matches the legal citation with capture group 1 having the last numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex `-(\d+)` to match the hyphen and the number and then read group with the number.

See https://www.regexpal.com/?fam=103376

Comment: Wow, that was fast and perfect.  Thank you for that answer.  Saved me hours of trying to plow through regex options.

Comment: @JackBoland if one of these answers is good/acceptable you should go ahead and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

To match the last number in the citation you could use

[`\d+(?=\.$)`](https://regex101.com/r/fE1Iqp/1)

This will match one or more digits (`\d+`)  before a dot (`\.`) and the end of the line (`$`).

Answer (score 0):

Your regex `(?!.*\d)` uses a negative lookahead ([zero length assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)) and asserts that what follows should not be a digit.

But if you actually want to match the last digits in the string you should update your regex to first match one or more digits `\d+` and then assert that there are no more digits following.

So you were on the right track and your final regex could look like:

[`\d+(?!.*\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/IgRr0D/1)

Answer (score 0):

This one was pretty challenging

To get the case name abbreviation i.e. `M. Kolbe Co. v. Armgus Textile Co.`

```
(?<=\s{1})([A-Z\.]{1,3}\s?[\w-]{3,10}\.?,?\s?[A-Z]?[\w-]{0,10}\.?,?\s?[A-Z]?[\w-]{0,10}\.?,?\sv\.\s[A-Z]{1}[\w-]{3,10}\.?,?\s?[A-Z]?[\w-]{0,10}\.?,?\s?[A-Z]?[\w-]{0,10}\.?\s?[A-Z]?[\w-]{0,10}\.?,?[A-Z\.]{0,3}\s?[\w-]{0,10})(?=,)
```